# Defining a function with variables that were previously introduced

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I have coefficients in a list:

```
allAs = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

And another list that is created with the Table function, with an "x" in each element which I want to find the derivative with respect to:

```
expTable = Table[Exp[-I*2 Pi*x*k], {k, 1, 5}];
```

My function is formed from the two lists above in the following way

```
function = Abs[1 - Total[allAs*expTable]]^2;
```

I would like to find the derivative of this function with Derivative, but the "x" is not in the function explicitly. How should I go about finding the derivative of function with respect to x.

I have tried to define the function as below before taking the derivative but it doesn't work:

```
function[_x] := Abs[1 - Total[allAs*expTable]]^2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

allAs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

expTable = Table[Exp[-I*2 Pi*x*k], {k, 1, 5}];
```

Use [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) and assuming that `x` is real

```
function[x_] = Abs[1 - allAs.expTable]^2 // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(* 2 (28 + 39 Cos[2 π x] + 24 Cos[4 π x] + 11 Cos[6 π x] + 
   Cos[8 π x] - 5 Cos[10 π x]) *)
```

The derivative is

```
function'[x] // Simplify

(* -4 π (39 Sin[2 π x] + 48 Sin[4 π x] + 33 Sin[6 π x] + 
   4 Sin[8 π x] - 25 Sin[10 π x]) *)

Column[Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {function[x], 
   function'[x]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `func[var_] := somestuff` is used when you want to define a function that you evaluate over and over. The `:=` means `SetDelayed` and the right-hand side is not evaluated until you call `func[]` with some argument. Also, the underscore should come after the x.

In this case, `function` already contains an expression that explicitly relies on x after your 3rd line of code. I would normally recommend `D[function, x]`. However, `Abs` is not differentiable so you will get a function that cannot be evaluated.

```
deriv = D[function, x]
deriv /. x -> 1
(* 2*((2*I*Pi)/E^(2*I*Pi*x) + (8*I*Pi)/E^(4*I*Pi*x) + 
   (18*I*Pi)/E^(6*I*Pi*x) + (32*I*Pi)/E^(8*I*Pi*x) + 
   (50*I*Pi)/E^(10*I*Pi*x))*Abs[1 - E^(-2*I*Pi*x) - 
   2/E^(4*I*Pi*x) - 3/E^(6*I*Pi*x) - 4/E^(8*I*Pi*x) - 
   5/E^(10*I*Pi*x)]*Derivative[1][Abs][-E^(-2*I*Pi*x) - 
   2/E^(4*I*Pi*x) - 3/E^(6*I*Pi*x) - 4/E^(8*I*Pi*x) - 
   5/E^(10*I*Pi*x) + 1]

   3080 I Pi Abs'[-14]
 *)
```

**EDIT:**

Also, my usual solution to define a function based on something previously evaluated, assuming `deriv = D[function, x]` yields something that can be evaluated, would be to write something like:

```
myfunc[x_] := deriv
```

and before evaluating, highlight `deriv` only, select the Evaluation menu > Evaluate in Place, or else

```
myfunc[x_] := Evaluate[derive]
```

There may be other, better ways.